# Unresolved External yet defined constructor?

Tags: c++, class, linker

I can not for the life of me figure out why the implementation functions aren't being seen and the call to the constructor is unresolved.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Error:

```
1>Debug\MeGLWindow.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
1>MeApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MeGLWindow::MeGLWindow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0MeGLWindow@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MeApp::MeApp(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0MeApp@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\FrizzleFry\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

App Header

```
#ifndef ME_APP
#define ME_APP

#include "MeGLWindow.h"
#include <string>

class MeApp {

private:
    MeGLWindow* meWind;
    std::string app;

public:

    MeApp() {}
    MeApp(std::string);
    ~MeApp();
    void run();

};


#endif
```

The implementation

```
#include "MeApp.h"

#include <SDL.h>
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <string>

MeApp::MeApp(std::string appName) {

    app = appName;
    meWind = new MeGLWindow(app);


}


MeApp::~MeApp() {

    //delete[] meWind;
    //meWind = NULL;

}

void MeApp::run() {

    bool quit = false;

    //Event handler
    SDL_Event e;

    //Enable text input
    SDL_StartTextInput();

    //While application is running
    while( !quit )
    {
        //Handle events on queue
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
        {
            //User requests quit
            if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                quit = true;
            }
            //Handle keypress with current mouse position
            else if( e.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT )
            {
                int x = 0, y = 0;
                SDL_GetMouseState( &x, &y );
                //handleKeys( e.text.text[ 0 ], x, y );
            }


            //meWind->show();
        }

        //Disable text input
        SDL_StopTextInput();
    }
}
```

The window header and implementation:

```
#ifndef ME_GL_WINDOW
#define ME_GL_WINDOW

#include "SDL.h"
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include "SDL_opengl.h"
#include "GL\glu.h"
#include <string>

class MeGLWindow {

private:
    std::string appName;

    int SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    SDL_Window* meWind;
    SDL_GLContext meContext;


public:

    MeGLWindow() {}
    MeGLWindow(std::string);
    ~MeGLWindow();
    void show();

};


#endif
```

cpp

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <string>

#include "MeGLWindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



MeGLWindow::MeGLWindow(std::string app) {

    appName = app;
    if(SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initilialize SDL!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 640;
    SCREEN_WIDTH  = 480;

    //Use OpenGL 3.1 core
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );

    //Create window
    meWind = SDL_CreateWindow( appName.c_str() , SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    if( meWind == NULL )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window!" << std::endl;
        exit(2);
    }

    meContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext( meWind );
    if( meContext = NULL ) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GL Context!" << std::endl;
        exit(3);
    }

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
    GLenum glewerror = glewInit();
    if( glewerror != GLEW_OK )
    {
        std::cout << "Error initializing GLEW!" << std::endl;
        exit(4);
    }

    //use vsync
    if( SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval( 1 ) < 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to set vsync!" << std::endl;
        //printf( "warning: unable to set vsync! sdl error: %s\n", sdl_geterror() );
    }

    //initialize opengl
    //( !initgl() )



}

MeGLWindow::~MeGLWindow() {
    //glDeleteProgram( gProgramID );

    //Destroy window    
    SDL_DestroyWindow( meWind );
    meWind = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}

void MeGLWindow::show() {

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow( meWind );

}
```

call file

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

#include "MeApp.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    MeApp app("My Application");

    app.run();

    return 0;
}
```

## EDIT

Well, I thought that maybe the .obj file was corrupted and had tried deleting it and rebuilding.  They were rebuilt but still gave me this error.

If I introduce non-sensical code (I added the line `a` in the MeGLWindow.h as a class member) and the build gloriously failed due to:

```
1>c:\users\frizzlefry\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\meglwindow.h(22): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'MeGLWindow'
1>c:\users\frizzlefry\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\meglwindow.h(22): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

I then went to the project directory and deleted the entire debug folder save the two .dll files.

I then deleted the nonsensical code and rebuilt the solution to no avail.  I received the same `unresolved external symbol` error.

When I originally created the files, I accidently named the file `meGLWindow.h` and I started getting this error after renaming the file.  It wouldn't let me just rename the file with a capital, it would say that the file already existed.  So I renamed it to something different, (2MeGLWindow.h) and then deleted the original file in the project folder and renamed it back to MeGLWindow.h

Then this error occured (but I had added code and didn't think this was the cause) especially since if I remove the MeGLWindow function calls (like `new MeGLWindow(app);`) then no build error occurs.  It's only if I try to have either the main function or the app class create an instance of MeGLWindow.

I'm considering just copy pasta into a new solution.  But maybe there are some sort of list of source files in the solution that are pointing to the wrong meGLWindow.h file that I originally created?

## EDIT2

Just got fed up, it was 5 files.  I made a new project, copy pasted the header and cpp files and it works like a charm.  I will never simply rename a header file ever again.

Comment: Ensure `MeGLWindow` is being compiled.If you are not sure if it is, add a line of hilariously bad code and make sure it breaks the build. If you still get the linker error, you've got a building problem.

Answer (score 1):

Warning LNK4042 is a bit deceptive, actually it means that object FILE was specified more that once, so for some reason you already have `MeGLWindow.obj`, and it does not contain a symbol for the `MeGLWindow(std::string)`, hence the error. Possible reasons are:

- Build can't delete old `MeGLWindow.obj` from the times when that constructor was not implemented yet.
- Build doesn't even try to delete old `MeGLWindow.obj`.
- Some other `MeGLWindow.obj` pops up in the build before the proper one.

Solution: try clean build/rebuild/manually deleting `Debug/MeGLWindow.obj`; Carefully check build options, output file names. Check security/UAC/access rights. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, can you check the edit section and see if that might shed some more light.

Comment: UAC is `YES (/MANIFESTUAC:)` and UAC execution level is `asInvoker`.. I don't really know anything about this or what it should be

Comment: good to know everything worked out, but that was some weird stuff.. renaming source files sometimes can lead to weird problems, but usually there is a way to get things back on track